# How to Compare two "DataSet" in C#

Tags: c#, dataset

I have 2 DataSet's in my code, I want to compare the equality of the data in these 2 dataset's.

Code:

```
DataSet dsXmlData1 = new DataSet();                
dsXmlData1.ReadXml(new StringReader(queryElements));

DataSet dsXmlData2 = new DataSet();
dsXmlData2.ReadXml(reader);
```

Comparision:

```
if(dsXmlData1 == dsXmlData2){}
```

In this example dsXmlData1 & dsXmlData2 are Dataset's.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare them like this too:

```
foreach (DataTable TblDefault in ds.Tables) \\ gridview values
{
        foreach (DataTable Tbldefault1 in ds1.Tables) \\databasevalues
         {
             if (TblDefault.TableName.ToUpper().Trim() == Tbldefault1.TableName.ToUpper().Trim())
             {
                  //Here
             }
         }
}
```

Comment: That only compares table name references, and not the data inside those tables.